# Why doesn't Stack Overflow Careers infer my name from my OpenID

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, openid

When I signed into Stack Overflow Careers with my OpenID, my provider asked me if I wanted to share my real name, nickname and email address with SOC. I figured that I might as well tick the box rather than having to type them in again, but it turned out SOC just ignored that information.

Would it be hard to pre-seed the name and email fields (and possibly other information, if other providers serve up more) with the values from my OpenID?

Comment: Depends on who your OpenID provider is and if they send the correct info across.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: [to ensure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65006/why-are-you-no-longer-inferring-user-names-from-openid/65019#65019) @replies work, and to not expose part of the OpenID identifier, as of mid September 2010 this information [is no longer made public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64531/what-happened-to-my-user-name/64541#64541).

---

At the time we wrote this code (a year ago) attribute exchange was very rough. Not all OpenID providers (eg GOOGLE) will give you this anyway. But, we should revisit it for providers that do.

Update: we now do OpenID 2.0 attribute exchange to request **email** and **real name**. This is tested and working on:

- Google
- Yahoo
- MyOpenID

And, presumably other compliant providers.

Comment: Errr, I *assume* the change to no longer show this, also applies to Careers? If not, then my edit was totally out of place...!