# What happened to my user name?

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My profile just went blank?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank)

My user name was/is `ring0`.

My ID is now `userXXXX` at stackoverflow, serverfault and meta!

What's happening?

Comment: You need to flag the moderators and tell them about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are no longer inferring usernames from openids.

If you want a username you must set one.

This is by design and will remain this way from this point onward.

Comment: Would have been nice to either send an email, or perform some kind of user-id conversion. I cannot believe this happened. Is it an isolated case?

Comment: Fixed via http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64433/username-missing-from-launchpad-openid-replaced-with-usernumber/64434#64434