# Nick name bug on stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to my user name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64531/what-happened-to-my-user-name)

Im not sure if this is the right place to report bugs (i guess no) but i just did not find any other (better) place to do so...

So my problem is that everywhere on stackoverflow i see user70542 instead of my real nick name psicho.... any idea why ? :)

Comment: Duplicate, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64531/what-happened-to-my-user-name and there are more.

Comment: I should point out that this **is** the place to report bugs.

Answer (score 1):

To change your username (what you are calling a "nick name"), simply click the "userXXXXX" you see at the top of the page. Then click the "Edit" link and enter your desired username.