# StackExchange suddenly forgot my name, is this a bug?

Tags: bug, openid, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to my user name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64531/what-happened-to-my-user-name)

Instead of calling my by my name all StackExchange sites started calling me names like  user291244. This started somewhere last week. Is this a bug, or is there another reason to be impersonal all of a sudden?

Comment: User #151405, you are hereby ordered to report to Room 139. These gentlemen will make sure you don't get lost on the way.

Comment: (Actually, all you have to do is edit your profile.)

Comment: And, so you don't get lost finding the profile, it's [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151405/user151405)

Answer (score 2):

Technically you never told it your name.  SE inferred the name from your open id.  They don't do that anymore, so the inferred name was dropped.

Comment: Interesting, so is it a bug, or was the feature dropped for a reason?