# Stack Overflow lost my user name and profile; but I can login

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My profile just went blank?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank)

I created a Stack Overflow account about six months ago using the OpenID "arx.myopenid.com" and Stack Overflow user name "arx" (I think).

When I log in now my user name has become "user292432" and my profile contains no information.

If I try to update my profile with a display name I consistently get the error "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!".

On this site I have (as you can see) successfully updated my display name to "arx".

Has anyone seen this before?  Or know if it can be fixed?

**Edit:**

I've found why the user name changed (it was a policy decision) but that doesn't explain why I can't update it.

Comment: The first part is because SO [stopped supporting a feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64531/what-happened-to-my-user-name/64541#64541)

Comment: That's funny, I just updated it to arx and it worked fine. You say you got an error multiple times? (@yhw42: there was no name at all, and anyway it would have said so instead of giving a generic error.)

Comment: @mmyers: Thank you for fixing it.  I tried it a few times over 24 hours and it failed with the same error each time.  Shall I mark this question as answered, or is someone likely to want to look at the underlying problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: you won't be able to update your profile with JavaScript disabled.

This is necessary to prevent profile spammers.

Comment: This was it.  I had enabled JavaScript for stackoverflow.com but not for sstatic.net.