# My username on meta doesn't match my SO username

Tags: support, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My profile just went blank?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/my-profile-just-went-blank)

My username on Stack Overflow is `trinithis`, but it displays as `user141119` here.

Comment: Go to your SO account profile, hit edit, and click `Copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts`

Comment: We used to make up a username for you based on your OpenID. That no longer happens. Now you gotta actually pick a name. For more, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65006/why-are-you-no-longer-inferring-user-names-from-openid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your username on any site you want.

Just click your username up top, and on your user page, there's an "edit" link near the top.  Click that, and you'll be able to set your name to whatever you like.

Why it's currently "user141119", though, i'm not sure.